# Read each csv file with filename and store it in Redshift table using AWS Glue job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

This code is giving a path error. I am trying to read the filename of each file present in an s3 bucket and then:

- Loop through these files using the list of filenames
- Read each file and match the column counts with a target table present in Redshift
- If the column counts match then load the table. If not, go in exception.

```py
import sys
import logging
from datetime import datetime,timedelta,date
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import json
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

if __name__ == "__main__":
   
    args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['TempDir','JOB_NAME','secret_name'])
    secret_name = args['secret_name']
    temp_dir = args['TempDir']
   
    sc = SparkContext()
    glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
    spark = glueContext.spark_session
    job = Job(glueContext)
    job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
   
    # getting redshift credentials
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name='us-east-1'
    )
     
    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        print("catch error:",e)
    else:
        # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
        # Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret = json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])
           
     # Username and password
    redshiftUserID = secret.get('username')
    redshiftPassword = secret.get('password')
   
    print("STARTED " + str(datetime.now()))
   
    #jdbc url for connection;
    jdbc_url = "jdbc:redshift://rcm-analytics-dev2.cvxngrljq9pn.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/rcmanalyticsdev2"
   
# Read CSV Files
Client_files = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={
        "paths": ["s3://rcma-chc-dev-analytics-cloud/merge/input"],'recurse':True
    },
    format_options={'withHeader': True},transformation_ctx = "Client_files"
)

print("S3 FILES ARE READ " + str(datetime.now()))
#extracting all the file names:
file_names=Client_files.toDF().withColumn("Filename",input_file_name()).select("Filename").distinct()

print("all files are:",file_names.show())
#MAKE LIST OF FILENAMES:
file_list=list(file_names)
#print EACH FILES FROM THE LIST:
for x in range(len(file_list)):
    print(file_list[x])

#PERFORM ETL JOB ON EACH FILE;
    
for obj in file_list:
    #each_clientfiles=spark.read.format("csv").option("header","True").option("path","obj").load()
    #each_clientfiles=each_clientfiles.toDF()
    
    each_clientfiles=glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={
        "paths": ["obj"],'recurse':True
    },
    format_options={'withHeader': True},transformation_ctx = "each_clientfiles"
    )
    
# Convert the DataFrame back to DynamicFrame
    #dynamicframe1 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(each_clientfiles, glueContext, "dynamicframe1")
#mapping files
    applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = each_clientfiles, mappings = [("org_code", "string", "org_code", "string"),("facility_code", "string", "facility_code", "string"),("facility","string","facility","string"),("review_uuid", "string", "review_uuid", "string"),("create_date", "timestamp", "create_date", "timestamp"),("create_user", "string", "create_user", "string"),("presentation_time", "timestamp", "presentation_time", "timestamp"), ("patient_ID", "string", "patient_ID", "string"),("encounter_ID", "string", "encounter_ID", "string"),("subset_id", "string", "subset_id", "string"),("subset_description", "string", "subset_description", "string"),("subset_data_version", "string", "subset_data_version", "string"),("episode_day","string","episode_day","string"),("review_status_last", "string", "review_status_last", "string"), ("phase_last", "string", "phase_last", "string"),("criteria_status_first", "string", "criteria_status_first", "string"),("criteria_status_last", "string", "criteria_status_last", "string"),("cp_count_checked_first", "int", "cp_count_checked_first", "int"),("cp_count_checked_last", "int", "cp_count_checked_last", "int"),("cp_count_w_clin_data", "int", "cp_count_w_clin_data", "int"), ("cp_id", "string", "cp_id", "string"),("choice_first", "string", "choice_first", "string"),("choice_last", "string", "choice_last", "string"),("source", "string", "source", "string"),("source_seq", "int", "source_seq", "int"),("group_seq", "int", "group_seq", "int"),("data_group", "string", "data_group", "string"),("description", "string", "description", "string"), ("type", "string", "type", "string"),("value", "string", "value", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

         #JDBC CONNECTION INPUTS
    conn_options = {
             "url": "jdbc:redshift://rcm-analytics-dev2.cvxngrljq9pn.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/rcmanalyticsdev2",
             "database":"rcmanalyticsdev2",
             "dbtable": "ODS_EPREMIS.CSV_MERGE_INTERQUAL",
             "user": redshiftUserID,
             "password": redshiftPassword,
             "redshiftTmpDir": args["TempDir"]
             }
             
    target_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("redshift", conn_options)

    frame = each_clientfiles.toDF()
    try:
        frame= frame.toDF(*[field.name for field in target_frame.schema().fields]) # note, number of columns must match!
        applymapping1 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(frame, glueContext, "final")

#DATAFRAME INSERTION IN THE REDSHIFT TABLE
        redshift_write = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(
            frame=applymapping1,
            catalog_connection = "acuity-redshift",
            redshift_tmp_dir ="s3://rcma-chc-dev-analytics-cloud/merge/temp/*",
            connection_options=conn_options,transformation_ctx = "redshift_write"
         )
    except Exception as e:
        print("Caught Exception",e)
        #print("Print file name:",obj)
    finally:    
        print("Glue job finished ", str(datetime.now()))
job.commit()
```

Comment: You have shown a LOT of code. It is unlikely that anyone will read through it all. Can you reduce the amount of code to just the part that is causing you the problem? Which line is generating the error? What is the _exact_ error message?

Comment: below line code having issue.....i am not able to read the data from the list ...each element of the list is having s3 path for file.

Comment: Please Edit your Question to show the line that is causing the error, and also show the exact error message.